# Combine several different sets of Linear Square Monte Carlo (LSMC) or Model Average

Tags: regression, linear-model, monte-carlo

I am doing a project similar to LSMC (Linear Square Monte Carlo) for prediction.

A Monte Carlo simulation engine is used to produce results, and a linear model is built on the same inputs and results.
However, the Monte Carlo results are not very convergent (the engine is too complex to increase the simulation times with my limited computational power), resulting in high variance of my linear model.

I ran the Monte Carlo simulation engine 5 times with different random seed to get 5 sets of result by the same input to enhance my linear model.

I think of 2 different approaches. Which one do you think is more proper?
Or any other ideas or advice/suggestion?

Approach 1: Combine all these 5 sets of results to get 5n observations to build one linear model.

Approach 2: Build 5 linear model on each of 5 data sets, and average 5 linear model results when predicting.

Approach 1 seems more easy, but 5 more times observations may overestimate the degree of freedom. This lead the linear model have too many terms or interactions by step AIC model selection. It will be overestimated.

Approach 2 seems more robust, but each data set may result in different linear model with different terms or interactions. This make interpretation and validation more difficult.

What are the advantages and disadvantages between these two approaches?
Any comment or ideas to discuss are highly appreciated.

Thank you.